# Controller not getting information (for the Model) sent from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I am getting all information from an HTML table inside my javascript array, which I send via an Ajax request to the Controller.
The view code: (Added)

```
    <table id="tblAuction" class="table table-striped" style="width:80%" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:150px">Image</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Goods ID</th>
                    <th style="width:150px">Description</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var items in Model.tbl_Goods)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @if (items.fileTobePosted != null)
                            {
                                <img src="@items.fileTobePosted" width="100" height="100" />
                            }
                            else
                            { <label>No picture</label>
                            }

                        </td>
                        <td>@items.GoodsInformation<
                        <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="fileTobePosted" type="file" id="fileTobePosted"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtGoodsInformation" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="txtDescription" /></td>
                    
                    <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Here is my JS and Ajax request:

```
   //js code to get all textboxes values

   $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
    var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
    var customers = new Array();
    $("#tblAuction TBODY TR").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var customer = {};
        customer.GoodsInformation = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
        customer.Description = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
        customers.push(customer);
    });        
    formdata.append("Goods", JSON.stringify(customers));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("test","Home")",
        data: formdata,    
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

And my controller where I want to get the information from.

```
    public ActionResult Test(tbl_Goods Goods)
    {                         
            HttpPostedFileBase fileTobePosted = Request.Files["fileTobePosted"];
            var getdata = Request.Form["auctionGoods"];
```

I get the file in filetobeposted which is fine.
I get the information also in

```
   var getdata
```

it shows: {goodsinformation, description}  respectfully.

But I want to loop through it because a user may add one or more rows. Like this.

```
   if (fileTobePosted != null)
            {
                //Loop through the forms
                for (int i = 0; i <= Request.Form.Count; i++)
                {
                   var GoodsInformation = Request.Form["GoodsInformation[" + i + "]"];
                    var Description = Request.Form["Description[" + i + "]"];
```

But Goodsinformation and Description returns NULL here.

Also, when hovering over my model, I get NULL

```
   public ActionResult Test(tbl_Goods Goods)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snippet but somethings were missing that I filled in myself.
**index.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
    <table id="tblAuction">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Info1</td>
                <td>Descr1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Info2</td>
                <td>Descr2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
            var customers = new Array();
            $("#tblAuction TBODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var customer = {};
                customer.GoodsInformation = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                customer.Description = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                customers.push(customer);
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/Test",
                data: JSON.stringify(customers),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then the Homecontroller.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class Goods
{
    public string GoodsInformation { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] List<Goods> goods)
    {
        return Ok(goods);
    }
}
```

When I press the save button I get the two TR lines in the goods parameter. I was unsure why you tried to create a formdata object and also why you where trying to get to the HttpPostedFileBase in the controller.

Comment: Hi Johan. Thank you for the contribution. Yes, in my html table, I am uploading an image, and text, in a row. That is why using the httppostefilebase. I am trying to save the image. I will edit my html code so that you can see.

Comment: Looking again ate you sample I wonder why you have the loop `$("#tblAuction TBODY TR").each ` since it looks like you are adding 1 item. Also you are already using razor syuntax so this must be a razor page or controller view, so why are you calling a `Home\Test` endpoint where you could, in a Razorpage use the PageModel. Is the endpoint **not** part of the page, and if so why?